# Why does Amazon RDS show a certificate authority when I'm not connecting via SSL/TLS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I'm not connecting to my Amazon RDS via SSL/TLS. Does anyone know why the certificate authority is still listed like so in the admin console?

[image: RDS console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All RDS instances are automatically configured with a TLS certificate that is used by the server if and when your client establishes a TLS connection.

Whether your application chooses to connect using TLS or not doesn't change the fact that the certificate is there, available for use.

What's actually indicated by this dropdown is which specific RDS CA signed the certificate that is automatically installed on your instance, because, if you are using TLS then your application needs to be expecting the same CA or validation will fail.  The available CA choices change over time as a matter of best practice, with old ones eventually retiring after new ones are created.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html